# Reading fragments from Redirect uri response from apple sign in

Tags: javascript, jsp, response, apple-sign-in

I am trying to do apple sign in. I have created **JSP file** for receiving the response sent from apple to the redirect uri. Apple sends code and id_tokena after authentication which I am trying to fetch in redirect URI file. But the problem that I am facing is with reading the parameters being sent to redirect URI. They are sending the response as a fragment rather than as a query string . It would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to read the fragments from the URL using the JSP.

I need help with reading parameters after the # in a url.

My redirect URL Looks like : http://localhost:8080/index.jsp#code=100&id_token=200 [I have changed the values]

**String code = request.getParameter("code");**  This returns null[image]

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: no not yet @RazvanCristianLung